# How to validate generic options in MapReduce?

Tags: mapreduce

I am passing a configuration properties file for a mapreduce program as `hadoop jar myprogram.jar -conf config-props.xml`

Within my run method, a Job object is created as below:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
// I want to validate that one configuration properties file is passed here
Job job = new Job(conf, getClass().getSimpleName());
```

While this works fine, I want to add code before creating a Job object to validate that I am sending one configuration properties file. Looking for help how is it done preferably using a GenericOptionsParser.

Answer (score 0):

GenericOptionsParser is a class that interprets common Hadoop command-line options and sets them on a Configuration object for your application to use as desired. You don’t usually use GenericOptionsParser directly, as it’s more convenient to implement the Tool interface and run your application with the ToolRunner, which uses GenericOptionsParser internally.

Check this link for more details on using GOP.[Link to GOP](http://kaniyarasu.com/2013/03/27/genericoptionsparser-tool-and-toolrunner-for-running-hadoop-job/)